# Symfony 2 SecureRandom() returns one character

Tags: symfony, constructor

In my group entity I generate a random key that serves as a "share code": people can invite and find each other with this code.
Here is how I use it:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Random Share Code generation
    $generator = new SecureRandom();
    $this->secureCode = $generator->nextBytes(15); 
}
```

It works but only one number is sent to my vachar field in DB. Am I doing anything wrong?
Thanks a bunch ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SecureRandom` generates random binary data, not random characters. If you use FOSUserBundle you can use their token generator:

```
$tokenGenerator = $container->get('fos_user.util.token_generator');
$shareCode = $tokenGenerator->generateToken();
```

Comment: As you can see [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-security-utilities) though, SecureRandom is supposed to generate a number.

Comment: The text suppose it, but the reality not. `nextBytes()` returns binary data. The article is old, the [actual API documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Util/SecureRandom.html#method_nextBytes) about it, states the fact.